# drag and drop in web page in java

Tags: java, jquery, struts

i would like to develop a web page which has the following

```
List A                      List B
  column name1              column name4
  column name2
  column name3
  column name4
  column nameN
```

I must be able to drag and drop the List A to List B

and finally save the values in `List A and List B`

how to do this in java web application using struts frame work?

Could any one of you help me on this please.

If jquery is the option than how to go about.?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery ui does that already](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) [min chars]

Answer (score 2):

You could do this a number of ways, mostly javascript, but HTML5 now supports drag and drop also.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp